# Add a hyperlink column for a Winforms DataGrid control

Tags: winforms

How can I add a hyperlink column for a Winforms DataGrid control?

Right now I am adding a string column like this

```
DataColumn dtCol = new DataColumn(); 
dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dtCol.ColumnName = columnName;
dtCol.ReadOnly = true;
dtCol.Unique = false;
dataTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);
```

I just need it to be a hyperlink instead of a String.  I am using C# with framework 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [DataGridViewLinkColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn(VS.90).aspx).

The link shows an example of setting up the column and adding it to a DGV::

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn links = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
links.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
links.HeaderText = ColumnName.ReportsTo.ToString();
links.DataPropertyName = ColumnName.ReportsTo.ToString();
links.ActiveLinkColor = Color.White;
links.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
links.LinkColor = Color.Blue;
links.TrackVisitedState = true;
links.VisitedLinkColor = Color.YellowGreen;

DataGridView1.Columns.Add(links);
```

You'll probably be interested in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn(VS.90).aspx) that shows how the snippet above fits into a more complete example of configuring DGV columns at runtime.

Comment: great answer! however, if you have a legacy DataGrid (as in the question), can you just add DataGridViewLinkColumn's to it and have it work or will you need to refactor out the DataGrid and replace with a DataGridView? Often there's a lot of styles and custom work in legacy DataGrid's which would have to be re-implemented from scratch...